# Simulator with iOS 11 not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios11

I have a mobile app that works perfectly fine on all devices (even with iOS 11 ) and all pre iOS 11 simulators.

When i try to start the app on an iOS 11 simulator i get this `dyld: dyld_sim not compatible mach-o`. I can't see any other information.

Anyone have any insight on what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

iPhone X and iPhone 8 [Plus] are x64 only devices, you need ALL your code and dependencies (frameworks and libraries) build for x64 simulator target.

Comment: Yes, but they can handle an x86 app, iPhone X and iPhone 8 [Plus] can't.

Comment: I see. But it dosent run on other simulators either, i mean like if i select iPhone 6 iOS 11 it dosen’t run.

Comment: Here I can only speculate that Apple has eliminated x86 runtime from iOS 11 simulator.

Comment: This is correct. iOS 11 is 64-bit only for all devices.